# How to show filtered logs on GCP Monitoring Dashboard

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, monitoring, google-cloud-logging

On the Google Cloud monitoring mosaic, we have a card that shows logs.  It's able to pre-filter on several fiels, for example the `severity` field screens logs below warning level as shown below.  Is there a similar way filter on text?  For example, I want the dashbaord to show only logs that match the text string "foobar".  I've tried adding `textPayload="foobar"` to the Query Editor to no avail.  Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: `textPayload="foobar"` will look exactly for that string in the field `textPayload` if applies. If you may need something more like finding logs that include the string `foobar` you may try `textPayload=~"foobar"`. If you want something more generic simply add `"foobar"` in the query. Another approach is to create your query directly in Cloud Logging and once you've got the right query, copy it to the Query Editor of your dashboard. I prefer more this approach since you have more visibility on which fields use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Sample queries using the Logs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library-preview?hl=en#kubernetes-filters) Docs.

*Container error logs for a specific pod containing a POST in the textPayload*

```
resource.type="k8s_container" AND
resource.labels.pod_name="POD_NAME" AND
textPayload:"POST" AND
severity=ERROR
```

You can also check the dropdown of error logs to see the code and copy the line to Query Editor for more filter options

You can check also [Logging Query Language](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language) for reference

Comment: Thank you I think my problem was notusing the colon `textPayload:` which is kind of strange given the other queries are = signes